# Name for a class that is not a derived class nor has virtual member functions

Tags: c++

In C++ parlance, is there a name for a type of class that does not inherit from any other class, has no virtual member functions, and is used as-is?

Comment: please share a snippet

Comment: [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).  Pick the one (or multiple ones) that closely matches your description.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific term for such classes. They are classes like any other.

Comment: Why is inheritance relevant? Absent polymorphism, inheritance us just a fancy notation for containment.

Comment: In the context where it is important to distinguish from a polymorphic class, the term I'd use is:  **non-polymorphic class**.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie type_traits is not a good resource, given it covers only  basic language constructs and qualifiers and leaves out even basic concepts such as regular classes/types.

Comment: @RAM.  The point of using type_traits is that you can create your own name by simply "and-ing" all of the traits you are seeking.  And you say it doesn't work for classes, then what is [std::is_class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class)?  And you say it has no virtual function, so what does [std::is_polymorphic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you didn't understood my points.  type_traits is not a good resource on terminology because it only covers basic language constructs and quantifiers.  type_traits also leaves out basic concepts such as regular classes/types.  A "regular class", or a "regular type", is a very specific C++ concept, coined by Alexander Stepanov in his "Fundamentals of Generic Programming" paper.  The whole point of my question is terminology to refer to a very specific concept.  It's completely irrelevant whether you can run type checks or not.

Comment: @RAM -- Instead of putting that information into the comment section late into the game, you should have put that information up front in the question itself.  Otherwise it is not clear what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there is no new information. Please check the question and the followup comments.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no term for a type that does not inherit from any other class and has no virtual member functions.

One reason that such classification isnt that useful is that private inheritance is an implementation detail. (Maybe you are refering to public inheritance only?)

The [`type_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library has lots of traits to query the category of a given type. See the below example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_trivial<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_pod<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_literal_type<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::has_unique_object_representations<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_empty<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_polymorphic<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_abstract<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_final<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_aggregate<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_signed<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_unsigned<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_bounded_array<Foo>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_unbounded_array<Foo>::value << "\n";    
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/E3fboEazq)

`Foo` is a trivial type, it is standard layout and it is a POD. It is neither polymorphic nor abstract. If you want a type that is not meant to be inherited from then you could make it `final` (`Foo` is not `final`).